# how to fix play controller error : incompatible types: long cannot be converted to List<General_store>

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

I was wanting to fetch the sum of table column data "amount" and return its sum as total. I appreciate your help

[image: models]

[image: Controllers method]

*Template code:*

```
@(tasks: List[General_store], taskForm: Form[General_store])
@main("current balance") {


<div class="col-md-5  col-md-offset-3   client-margin">
    <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          current Balance
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body"> <br/><br/><br/>
            @for(storedb <- tasks) {



                <p>
                    <b >Balance:</b>@storedb.amount
                </p>


            }

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
}
```

Comment: I embedded the images so one does not need to follow hyperlinks to get all the information.
However, the code should be added as text rather than images. Additionally you should describe precisely what you want the code to do and what it actually does.

Comment: Well, I want the code to print on views the sum of  mysql table column

Comment: Post the `balance.scala.html` template. I think your parameters are wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem** is with the parameters of your template. You have specified two parameters - a list of stores and a form

`@(tasks: List[General_store], taskForm: Form[General_store])`

But from your controller you actually provide a long (`General_store.sumOfStores()`) and a form (`taskData`). You see that the number of parameters matches but not the type of parameters

---

**The solution:** you have to change your controller code from:

`return ok(views.html.balance.render(General_store.sumOfStores(), taskData)`

to:

`return ok(views.html.balance.render(General_store.sumOfStores(), General_store.all(), taskData)`

and your template parameter definition from

`@(tasks: List[General_store], taskForm: Form[General_store])`

to:

`@(totalSum: Long, tasks: List[General_store], taskForm: Form[General_store])`

If you then want to display the sum on the page you have to add this line to the template (for example after `<div class="panel-body">`:

`<h2>Total sum is: @totalSum</h2>`

Comment: Thanks the error is no longer there, but result gives me list as usual ,but no sum

Comment: Glad to hear ti! Please consider accepting the answer if it helped - as with the previous question you had. This is the social protocol here at StackOverflow and you won't get much help from people if you don't show them appreciation :)

Comment: Wow ! good place really , i thank anyone who is helping me to grow up my skills in java . please share this maybe it will help others like me.

Comment: @user3518835 well then go ahead and accept and upvode (you will get reputation as well)